# React Native - Share local image with showShareActionSheetWithOptions

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, share

I have a question about sharing a local image with `showShareActionSheetWithOptions`.

Here is my code:

```
ActionSheetIOS.showShareActionSheetWithOptions({
  title: "React Native",
  message: "Hola mundo",
  url: '@theme/img/share/share.png',
  subject: "Share Link" //  for email
});
```

From the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/actionsheetios.html):
"If URL points to a local file, or it is a base64-encoded URI, the file it points to will be loaded and shared directly".

But it doesn't work. I am not really sure how to access or how to get the path to the image. In my app root folder (where the index.io.js is located) I have a "src/theme/img"-folder where all my images are.

In the example from react-native they have the image exactly where the .js file is, but this doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

In current React Native version (0.49), valid URLs can be:

- chosen from `ImagePicker` of Expo API
- screenshot taken via `ReactNative.takeSnapshot('window')`

The path looks like:

```
/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A8EA990-D8C0-43B9-A527-365111FCBBA0/tmp/ReactABI21_0_0Native/9BD50E06-3D6F-4E44-9465-A17D6BE399D4.png
```

or

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7A8EA990-D8C0-43B9-A527-365111FCBBA0/Library/Caches/ExponentExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Ftestapp2-d4b9a2f3-ffbf-4cba-8b8d-cd555cd62ca8/ImagePicker/2D289B12-4090-4F66-AE2B-BCDDB1C3086C.jpg
```

However, local image URLs like `./theme/img/share/share.png` is not supported. By the way, `asset-library://` URLs are not supported either.